# Ansible returns wrong hosts in dynamic inventory (private ip collision?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two instances on *different* VPCs which have the same private address.

ci-vpc:

```
172.18.50.180:
    tags:
        Environment: ci
        Role: aRole
```

test-vpc:

```
172.18.50.180:
    tags:
        Environment: test
        Role: web
```

I am running the following playbook:

```
- name: "print account specific variables"
  hosts: "tag_Environment_ci:&tag_Role_web"
  tasks:
    - name: "print account specific variables for account {{ account }}"
      debug:
        msg:
          - 'ec2_tag_Name': "{{ ec2_tag_Name }}"
            'ec2_tag_Role': "{{ ec2_tag_Role }}"
            'ec2_private_ip_address': "{{ ec2_private_ip_address }}"
            'ec2_tag_Environment': "{{ ec2_tag_Environment }}"
```

Since I am asking for ***both*** role web and environment ci, none of these instances should be picked, but nevertheless the result that I am getting is:

```
ok: [172.18.50.180] => {
  "changed": false,
  "msg": [
      {
          "ec2_private_ip_address": "172.18.50.180",
          "ec2_tag_Environment": "test",
          "ec2_tag_Name": "test-web-1",
          "ec2_tag_Role": "web"
      }
  ]
}
```

Obviously this instance does not meet the requirements under `hosts`...

It seems like `ec2.py` searched for the `Environment` tag, found ci for 172.18.50.180, then searched separately for the role tag, found another one under 172.18.50.180, and just marked that instance as ok, even though these are *two different instances on different vpcs*.

I've tried changing `vpc_destination_variable` in `ec2.ini` to `id` but then I'm getting error when Ansible is trying to connect to these instances because it cannot connect to the id...

```
fatal: [i-XXX]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname i-XXX: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true
}
```

Is there another option that will work under `vpc_destination_variable`? Any known solution for such a collision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: This is exactly what `hostname_variable` in `ec2.ini` is for, as documented:

```
# This allows you to override the inventory_name with an ec2 variable, instead
# of using the destination_variable above. Addressing (aka ansible_ssh_host)
# will still use destination_variable. Tags should be written as 'tag_TAGNAME'.
```

Unfortunetely I've missed it and found it after looking around in `ec2.py`

**Longer answer with additional options to hostnames**

After finding out about `hostname_variable`, I had another problem that it can receive *only one* variable. In my case I had some instances with the same private ip on one hand, and some with the same tags on the other (AWS autoscaling groups, same tags on all hosts), so I needed a way to differentiate between them.

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aviadpines/fd741015d700dfabb75ead404f7c0473) with this option. My change is in line 848. This allows you to use multiple comma separated variables in `hostname_variable`, e.g.:

```
hostname_variable = tag_Name,private_ip_address
```